# Semantic UI. How to initialize a pop-up on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I'm new with Sematic UI and jQuery, and I want to show a pop-up when I click on button "Browse1", not on "Browse2" or "Browse3.

But the pop-up also shows when I click anywhere on my menu. How can I restrict the pop-up, so it only displays when clicking on "Browse1"?

Why doesn't the following work?

```
$(".ui.menu").find("a:first").popup({on: 'click'});
```

Here's my code:

```js
$(".ui.menu").popup({on: 'click'});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui menu">
    <a class="browse item">
        Browse1 <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="browse item">
        Browse2 <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="browse item">
        Browse3 <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="ui fluid popup bottom left transition hidden">
    <div class="ui four column relaxed equal height divided grid">
        <div class="column">
            <h4 class="ui header">Fabrics</h4>
            <div class="ui link list">
                <a class="item">Cashmere</a>
                <a class="item">Linen</a>
                <a class="item">Cotton</a>
                <a class="item">Viscose</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h4 class="ui header">Size</h4>
            <div class="ui link list">
                <a class="item">Small</a>
                <a class="item">Medium</a>
                <a class="item">Large</a>
                <a class="item">Plus Sizes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h4 class="ui header">Colored</h4>
            <div class="ui link list">
                <a class="item">Neutrals</a>
                <a class="item">Brights</a>
                <a class="item">Pastels</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h4 class="ui header">Types</h4>
            <div class="ui link list">
                <a class="item">Knitwear</a>
                <a class="item">Outerwear</a>
                <a class="item">Pants</a>
                <a class="item">Shoes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's something funky with the popup()-function, which you're not showing, because if I try the exact same code using `$('.browse')` or `$('.browse.item')` it still doesn't work, which leads me to believe that function expects something very specific for it to work.

Comment: I took popup()-function from this docs http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#/usage

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Semantic UI way of assigning a popup to the menu element (in your case the first item). Check this script below I wrote for you.

```js
$('.ui.menu .item:first-child').popup({
    popup : $('.ui.popup'),
    on : 'click'
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui menu">
    <a class="browse item">
        Browse1 <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="browse item">
        Browse2 <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="browse item">
        Browse3 <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="ui fluid popup bottom left transition hidden">
    <div class="ui four column relaxed equal height divided grid">
        <div class="column">
            <h4 class="ui header">Fabrics</h4>
            <div class="ui link list">
                <a class="item">Cashmere</a>
                <a class="item">Linen</a>
                <a class="item">Cotton</a>
                <a class="item">Viscose</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h4 class="ui header">Size</h4>
            <div class="ui link list">
                <a class="item">Small</a>
                <a class="item">Medium</a>
                <a class="item">Large</a>
                <a class="item">Plus Sizes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h4 class="ui header">Colored</h4>
            <div class="ui link list">
                <a class="item">Neutrals</a>
                <a class="item">Brights</a>
                <a class="item">Pastels</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h4 class="ui header">Types</h4>
            <div class="ui link list">
                <a class="item">Knitwear</a>
                <a class="item">Outerwear</a>
                <a class="item">Pants</a>
                <a class="item">Shoes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```